# Midpoint of two line segments in three dimensions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, 3d

This might be an easy question, but since i'm new to solid shapes, i couldn't solve it. A= (7,1,3) B=(5,1,2) C=(4,-2,3) D=(6,m,n) I need to find m and n so that segments BD and AC have the smae midpoint. I wrote the midpoint formula for AC and found its midpoints and then tried to equate it with the midpoints of the segment DC, but i have 2 unknowns there and couldn't find m and n. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You have the midpoint for $AC$? But then the midpoint of BD must match it in all three coordinates.  The first slot you get for free, each of the other two just works out to one equation in one unknown.

Comment: That is correct, but the first slow AC is 1.5 and BD is 0.5; they mismatch, isn't this an issue?

Comment: Well it would be if it were true...The midpoint between $(a,b,c)$ and $(x,y,z)$ is $(\frac {a+x}{2},\frac {b+y}{2},\frac {c+z}{2})$.

Comment: (7-4)=1.5 for AC and for BD (6-5)/2=0.5, no? Oh I confused this with the distance formula. Pardon, problem solved! Thanks

Comment: You are taking differences where you should be adding.  The coordinates of the midpoint are the average of the coordinates.  Oh, I see you worked it out.  Great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The midpoint of $AC$ has coordinates:
$$
M_{AC}=\left(\frac{x_A+x_C}{2},\frac{y_A+y_C}{2},\frac{z_A+z_C}{2}\right)=\left(\frac{11}{2},-\frac{1}{2},3 \right)
$$
In the same way,the midpoint of $BD$ has coordinates:
$$
M_{CD}=\left( \frac{11}{2},\frac{1+m}{2},\frac{2+n}{2}\right)
$$

so we want:
$$
\frac{1+m}{2}=-\frac{1}{2} \quad \land \quad \frac{2+n}{2}=3
$$
two equations for two unknowns.